# Nginx ingress - escape characters

Tags: nginx, rewrite, kubernetes, nginx-ingress

I have the following ingress conf that is exposed via nodePort 32100. When I call (curl) the URL [1] which contains parenthesis, I get HTTP 500 error. But when I call the URL [2] which contains no parenthesis, request passes successfully via the NGINX ingress controller (v0.35.0).

```
apiVersion: extensions/v1beta1
kind: Ingress
metadata:
  annotations:
    nginx.ingress.kubernetes.io/proxy-body-size: 0m
    name: test1-app-ingress
  namespace: test1
spec:
  rules:
  - host: ing1.example.com
    http:
      paths:
      - backend:
          serviceName: test1-app-1-ingress
          servicePort: 80
        path: /test1
  - host: ing2.example.com
    http:
      paths:
      - backend:
          serviceName: test1-app-2-ingress
          servicePort: 80
        path: /test1
```

[1]

```
curl  "http://ing1.example.com:32100/test1/test1.json/Streams(Type_4000000)" -X POST --data-binary @25kfile 
* About to connect() to ing1.example.com port 32100 (#0)
*   Trying 10.10.10.30...
* Connected to ing1.example.com (10.10.10.30) port 32100 (#0)
> POST /test1/test1.json/Streams(Type_4000000) HTTP/1.1
> User-Agent: curl/7.29.0
> Host: ing1.example.com:32100
> Accept: */*
> Content-Length: 25000
> Content-Type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded
> Expect: 100-continue
>
< HTTP/1.1 100 Continue
< HTTP/1.1 500 Internal Server Error
< Server: nginx
< Date: Tue, 01 Mar 2022 20:08:07 GMT
```

application's log:

```
10.113.4.0 - - [01/Mar/2022:20:08:07 +0000] "POST /test1/test1.json/Streams(Type_4000000) HTTP/1.0" 500 528 "-" "curl/7.29.0" 25283 0.004 [test1-test1-app-1-ingress-80] [] 10.113.4.157:80 528 0.003 500 4b3fd4d41fb8a2d26691bd2da78f24b
```

[2]

```
curl  "http://ing1.example.com:32100/test1/test1.json/StreamsType_4000000" -X POST --data-binary @25kfile 
* About to connect() to ing1.example.com port 32100 (#0)
*   Trying 10.10.10.30...
* Connected to ing1.example.com (10.10.10.30) port 32100 (#0)
> POST /test1/test1.json/StreamsType_4000000HTTP/1.1
> User-Agent: curl/7.29.0
> Host: ing1.example.com:32100
> Accept: */*
> Content-Length: 25000
> Content-Type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded
> Expect: 100-continue
>
< HTTP/1.1 100 Continue
< HTTP/1.1 200 OK
< Server: nginx
< Date: Tue, 01 Mar 2022 20:09:59 GMT
```

application's log:

```
172.28.120.65 - - [01/Mar/2022:20:09:59 +0000] "POST /test1/test1.json/StreamsType_4000000 HTTP/1.0" 200 0 "-" "curl/7.29.0" 25281 0.003 [test1-test1-app-1-ingress-80] [] 10.113.4.157:80 0 0.003 200 133bbb4f7149d31e75cf78158566efee
```

Is this an issue on the NGINX IC? should I escape any characters on the ingress configuration, like the parenthesis?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The application's log file indicates that the request reaches the application. This means that the "500" error code is sent by the application. Therefore you cannot do anything on nginx side to fix this situation.

You need to make sure application properly processes the request.